# How do I reload my database in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

I understand that I can reload the data model by typing this

```
> reload!
```

But I am wondering if there is a similar way to reload the data itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure where else you would reload it from.. fixtures, maybe? Sometimes you need to force the object to update itself, eg.

```
@model_instance = MyModel.first
@model_instance.reload #=> forces the object to reflect the most recent info from the db
```